# Clock app doesn't work

Tags: c#

I am working currently on my clock application in C# in Visual Studio 2015.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t.Interval = 1000;               
        t.Tick() += new EventHandler(this.t_Tick);
        t.Start();
    }
```

and this part `t.Tick() += new EventHandler(this.t_Tick);` has some kind of problem shown here:

[image]

I would appreciate it if you provided me with a full explanation of this issue.

ERROR LIST:

1) Error    CS0079  The event 'Timer.Tick' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

2) Error    CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'sender' of 'EventHandler'

Comment: Tick is an event you are subscribing to, not a method - remove the brackets: `t.Tick += new EventHandler(this.t_Tick);`

Comment: Your image of text isn't very helpful.  It can't be copied
into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, making other
users with the same problem less likely to find the answer
here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant
text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid
transcription errors).

Comment: Even if `Tick` were a method, this would be syntactically incorrect as they can't be set or bound to in this manner.

Comment: Since you mentioned in your title that it's a clock app: Timer is not very precise. An `Intervall` of 1000 [ms] only guarantees that the time between two ticks will be **at least** 1000 ms. So every couple of seconds you will skip a value. I'd recommend using a smaller value (e.g. 250 ms) to update your clock.

Answer (score 5):

[Tick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick(v=vs.110).aspx) is an event, not a method, so you need to do:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    t.Interval = 1000;               
    t.Tick += new EventHandler(this.t_Tick);
    t.Start();
}
```